# Array in for loop in a BASH function

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

```
    function bookExistCheck {

    for i in "${bookTitle[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$1" == "${bookTitle[$i]}" ]; then
            if [ "${bookAuthor[$i]}" == "$2" ]; then
                bookExist=true
                echo "Book already exist in database."
            fi
        fi
    done

}
```

I am tryring to write a function that takes in 2 variables, title and author and then check if it already exist. BookTitle and BookAuthor are arrays which already hold values of book titles and authors. Currently with the above code, im getting an error on the line

```
 if [ "$1" == "{$bookTitle[$i]}" ]; then
```

The error says

> ./menu.sh: line 25: Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince: syntax error
>   in expression (error token is "Potter - The Half Blood Prince")

I am pretty new to BASH so my guess is a synthax error?

Comment: try `"${bookTitle[$i]}"`

Comment: @delta Isnt that what my code currently is ? If you meant change [@] to [$i], that also doesnt work.

Comment: sorry. you have a single line `if [ "$1" == "{$bookTitle[$i]}" ]; then`. But the full function code is right.

Comment: can you give the input of `bookExistCheck`, and also `bookTitle` and `bookAuthor`?

Comment: @delta im sorry but i still dont understand what you are suggesting. That line is suppose to compare what i have stored in $bookTitle[i] to the first argument passed which is stored in $1

Comment: @delta

bookExistCheck inputs are any 2 random strings. Both inputs will be stored in $1 and $2.

BookTitle[0] is Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince and bookAuthor[0] is J.K Rowling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `for i in "${bookTitle[@]}"`, `i` isn't index of array, it's already element of array.

Try to write something like this: `if [ "$1" == "${i}" ]; then`

**EDIT**

You can also use `for` loop:

```
for (( i=0; i<=${#bookTitle[@]}; i++ )); do
```

In this case, `i` will take indexes from 0 to `bookTitle` size.

Comment: OMG... I confused this for loop to the other for loop for($i=0;$i++....)

Thank you for this. Your suggestion would work but i also have another bookAuthor argument i need to compare. Should i just put another for loop inside the bookTitle loop?